# How to change MAPI MessageClass in Exchange 2010?

Tags: c#, mapi, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to get Exchange 2010 to change the MessageClass (PR_MESSAGE_CLASS) of an incoming message to that of my custom form (IPM.Note.MyCustom) when the incoming message has a certain header set. (`X-MyCustomHeader: Yes`)

I have seen some information about setting another MIME header (`Content-Class:`) that Exchange will use to set the MessageClass, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  (I've seen examples that use `Content-Class: MyCustom` and `Content-Class: urn:content-class:custom.MyCustom`)

I've even looked into writing a transport agent with C#, and I did find a `MapiMessageClass` property on the `EmailMessage` class, but it's read-only.  I also looked at added a MAPI property in a TNEF section, but the Exchange API does not offer a way to create a TNEF section if one does not already exist.  (And most mail from the Internet doesn't.)

There's got to be a way to do this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

We do it using Outlook Remption: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/RDOMail.htm  The MessageClass property of RDOMail is Read/Write.  Redemption just wraps Extended MAPI though so you could do it with native code if you don't want to use a 3rd party library.